# Initialize matrix with conditions without a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vectorization

I want to create a matrix `M` with indices `i,j` so that `M(i,j)=i/j`. I could do this using two loops but is there any way to do this without using `for` loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create two vectors of indices. Make one vertical, one horizontal. Then use `bsxfun()` to divide elementwise.

```
i = (1:9)'; % '
j = 1:5;

M = bsxfun(@rdivide,i,j);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use vector multiplication, like this:

```
row=1:10;
col=1:10;
M=row'*(1./col);
```

Comment: Funny. I tested my solution against yours. And the results differ marginally for some indices. There is a small error due to lost information in the multiplication.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that `bsxfun`, or `ndgrid` will be slower than the classic strength of Matlab- matrices operations. Do you have an idea why my solution is the slowest..? What is the lost of information in the multiplication?

Comment: Your solution is the fastest. ``ndgrid()`` the slowest. The difference in our solutions is probably because ``1./col`` is a numerical value which is already rounded at the last digit. This rounding error will be multiplied and therefore appear in the solution.

Comment: @Adiel I think `matrix-mul` shines when there is reduction in dimension. In this case, we have an expansion instead. I recently did some benchmarks comparing `bsxfun(@times` with `matrix-mul` when both are fed a column and a row vector and `bsxfun` seemed to have the upper hand. So, it seems that trend continues with division operation too.

Comment: For the difference. ``5/3 == 5*(1/3)`` returns ``false`` which is why it is best practice to check for something like ``a-b<e-15``.

Comment: Thank for the explanations, nice to know it all.

Answer (score 0):

The `./` notation indicates element wise operation.

```
[m,n]=ndgrid(1:9,1:5);
M = m./n;
```

(I don't like to use `i` AND `j` because you make referencing `sqrt(-1)` complicated.)